# how to set the protobuf format in MQTT protocol

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, mqtt

I am trying to define my mqtt packet structure through protobuf I implemented following code for publish message by using protobuf

**Code :**

```
 package com.cupola.demo;

 import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
 import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
 import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
 import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
 import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence;

public class Publish {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Sample sas = new Sample();
    String topic = "Cupola";
    String content = sas.passMessage(24,"Noor");
    int qos = 2;
    String broker = "tcp://localhost:1883";
    String clientId = "DemoPublish";
    MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();

    try {
        MqttClient sampleClient = new MqttClient(broker, clientId, persistence);
        MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
        connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
        System.out.println("Connecting to broker: " + broker);
        sampleClient.connect(connOpts);
        System.out.println("Connected");
        System.out.println("Publishing message: " + content);
        MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(content.getBytes());
        message.setQos(qos);
        sampleClient.publish(topic, message);
        System.out.println("Message published");
        sampleClient.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Disconnected");
//            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (MqttException me) {
        System.out.println("reason " + me.getReasonCode());
        System.out.println("msg " + me.getMessage());
        System.out.println("loc " + me.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.out.println("cause " + me.getCause());
        System.out.println("excep " + me);
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Here is the set values through call the function from Publisher and set the values according to proto file

```
package com.cupola.demo;

import com.cupola.demo.CatProto.Cat;

public class Sample {

public String  passMessage(int age,String name) {

    // creating the cat
    Cat noor= CatProto.Cat.newBuilder()
            .setAge(age)
            .setName(name) 
            .build();
    String message=noor.toString();


    return message;
}
```

}

**This is my Cat.proto file :**

```
option java_outer_classname="CatProto";

message Cat {
optional int32 age = 1;
required string name = 2;
}
```

is it right or i need to change the way. Please suggest me. Advance thanking you.

Comment: What problem are you actually seeing here?

Comment: I want to fill a mqtt packet attributes and the message format should be define by protobuf. So the above mention code is it okay for my requirement or i need to modified more. Thanks for quick reply

Comment: Which java protobuffer library are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your using the Google [Protobuff](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial) library then you want to be using `toByteArray()` not `toString()` in your `passMessage()` method.

```
public byte[]  passMessage(int age,String name) {

    // creating the cat
    Cat noor= CatProto.Cat.newBuilder()
            .setAge(age)
            .setName(name) 
            .build();
    byte message[] = noor.toByteArray();


    return message;
}
```

Comment: and i need to declare message as a byte[] other wise it rise an error and thanks for your suggestions